# Cost sensitive evaluation metrics: precision, recall and F-measure

Tags: machine-learning, classification, model-evaluation

How can I compute precision, recall and F-measure when we define a cost matrix for evaluation?

In my problem I have 3 different classes, and some errors are more dangerous than others. I would like my evaluation metrics to take into account this information.

Comment: Given that you mention having 3 classes,  I assume you're interested in evaluating a classification model. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

> In my problem I have 3 different classes, and some errors are more
>   dangerous than others. I would like my evaluation metrics to take into
>   account this information.

Misclassification cost should cover this sufficiently in my opinion.

Assuming a classification problem with 3 classes 
$$Y=\{y_1,y_2,y_3\}$$
and a cost matrix 
$$C=\begin{bmatrix}0 & c_{12} & c_{13}\\ c_{21} & 0 & c_{23}\\c_{31}&c_{32}&0 \end{bmatrix}$$

with the diagonal indicating no costs for correct classification and cost $c_{12}$ entailed by predicting an instance of $y_1$ to be $y_2$ instead.
Not that the cost matrix need not by symmetric and, based on your problem description, shouldn't be.

From your model, generate the [confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix) (I will denote it as $\hat{Y}$ for lack of other notation) for your validation set and multiply it with $C$ to get the misclassification cost of your model

$$ 
MCC= \hat{Y} \times C
$$

When evaluating different models, lower misclassification cost is of course preferred

Answer (score 0):

Note that, the term **precision** and **recall** is defined in **binary classification** case. (Same as other terms, such as false positive, false negative, etc.)

If you have 3 classes and want to use the **precision** and **recall** metrics, you need to define what is "positive" or "negative". [One vs. all others](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/lecture/68Pol/multiclass-classification-one-vs-all) is one way of defining it. For example, I want to classify three animals, cat dog and rabbit, I can define detecting cat is "positive". After the definition, these metrics (precision recall, false positive rate etc.) can be used.

A related discussion can be found in my answer here

[Calculate accuracy using true/false positives/negatives](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/267662/calculate-accuracy-using-true-false-positives-negatives/267664#267664)